# What are the main differences between the original Stargate SG-1 and the Final Cut edition?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I just got Amazon Prime video so I can rewatch the *Stargate* series.  I remember things a little differently then I am seeing it.

For instance, I distinctly remember Carter saying (when first getting to Abidos)

> we had to MacGyver a bunch of supercomputers together

as a joke to Richard Dean Anderson.  However, she says jerry-rig instead.  Is that something that they changed or am I remembering it all wrong?

Are there any other big changes done that I will be surprised at?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.gateworld.net/news/2009/07/review-stargate-sg-1-children-of-the-gods-final-cut/amp/

Comment: Hi there. I've taken the liberty to rewrite that a bit to make it a better fit for the site, by asking about the differences only; recommendations on where to watch one version or another are off-topic. If you want to focus more on one aspect or another (to narrow the scope a but), feel free to [edit] the question further.

Comment: BW: Listen, there's a change… (Pause to listen to dialog)… took out the MacGyver thing.

RDA: Yeah! Very nice.

BW: You know why?

RDA: Unh uh.

BW: Cause now you're Jack O'Neill. Why, why back-reference two series ago?

RDA: Hmmm, don't know.

BW: Do you want it back?

RDA: Do I want it back? No.

BW: I can do it again, but I can't do it for another 10 years. (Laughter)

RDA: Ok. I'll wait that decade.

BW: Ok. (Laughter)

RDA: I have no problems with it disappearing. I think it was for the audience primarily anyway. - https://tinyurl.com/yylakkw9

Answer (score 12):

You likely watched the ["Final Cut"](https://www.gateworld.net/news/2009/07/review-stargate-sg-1-children-of-the-gods-final-cut) version. The special effects and score were largely redone, and various scenes cut (including one instance of full-frontal nudity) mostly to get it from an R to a PG.

Dialogue changes were mostly for Sam Carter, to make her characterisation more consistent with later episodes. As well as the MacGyver reference, the infamous "my reproductive organs are on the inside" line was removed.

A few scenes were also extended to fix other issues, such not redialling an outgoing wormhole in the intro.